# Type Eror : fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to use the library [naturalNode](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural#bayesian-and-logistic-regression) in my angular web app. I understand that fs.readFileSync does not work with the client side server. What is the way around to use this library? I am trying to use its Logistic regression function.

Comment: You can try using the `babel-plugin-static-fs` as part of your build assuming you need to read the file at build time and not runtime.

Comment: A browser is not going to let you read an arbitrary file if that’s what you’re trying to do.